# Using delegate to push data back

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I use this code, but "it works" doesn't happen.

DetailViewController.h

```
[#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol ProtocolNameDelegate

-(void)DoSomething;

@end

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController {
     id<ProtocolNameDelegate> _delegate;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) id<ProtocolNameDelegate> _delegate;
```

DetailViewController.m

```
@synthesize _delegate;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [_delegate DoSomething];
}
```

MasterViewController.h

```
@interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController <ProtocolNameDelegate>
```

MasterViewController.m

```
-(void)DoSomething
{
    NSLog(@"It works");

}
```

I think i have to add something like:

```
MasterViewController* mvc = [[MasterViewController alloc] init];
    mvc._delegate = self;
```

But it gives an error, and by the way will it create another instance of MasterViewController?

Comment: You are creating delegate in detailViewController how could you access it from an object of masterViewController

Comment: do u mean #include "DetailViewController.h" ?

Comment: there is good explanation on SO, check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
MasterViewController* mvc = [[MasterViewController alloc] init];
mvc._delegate = self;
```

write this,

```
DetailViewController* svc = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
dvc._delegate = self;
```

You made mistake in implementation.

Abstract of implementation should be.

- Create Protocol in DetailVC.
- Create Property for Delegate, Synthesize, and make call.
- Import DetailVC in MasterVC and include delegate in MasterVC.h
- Implement protocol method in MasterVC.m
- Create instance of DetailVC and assign `DetailVCObj.delegate = self;`

Comment: and i will have 2 instances of DetailViewController?

Comment: No you need only one at the place from where you are presenting/pushing detailview.

Comment: i think it's because in this case i actually have 2 of them

Comment: Try to do one thing. place button on detail and on button click call delegate method and test if it is working.

Comment: fixed that using  SecondViewController *secondVC =
            (SecondViewController *) segue.destinationViewController;
        [secondVC setDelegate:self];

Answer (score 0):

In `MasterViewController.m`, you need to allocate and intialise `DetailViewController` somewhere

```
DetailViewController* dvc = [[DetailViewControlleralloc] init];
    dvc._delegate = self;
```

Also, because you have written `[_delegate doSomething]` in

`DetailviewController's viewDidLoad` method,

it means you must set  `dvc._delegate = self;` in `MasterViewController.m`

before loading **dvc's view** (before addSubview or anything that loads view).

Comment: this made my code ok:  SecondViewController *secondVC =
            (SecondViewController *) segue.destinationViewController;
        [secondVC setDelegate:self];